# Dark mode/Splash activity follows the system . Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-night-mode

I'm developing an app. I have implemented dark mode by creating colors-night file , using a switch and appCompatDelegate. I have written some code so that the app doesn't follow the system when phone's dark mode is on . And it works properly. Yet, the Splash screen does not obey and appears dark-colored when phone's dark mode is on(while the app continues light). I know this happens because the system reads the night resources before launching. (I figured it out since disabling dark mode in the onCreate method in SpashActivity or in Application does not work(and did some research) ). Adding "forceDark = false" on xmls doesnt work either. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I know it would be better to leave it this way since it is user's preference but i want on the first use, the user to see my company's colors and logo and then, choose the dark theme. Which, i also cant find how to change. I mean change dynamically splash activity's color depending on the sharedPreferences. (as i said before, doesnt work).

Thank you in advance :slight_smile:

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.